# About finding marginal PDF,E(Y|X=x) and condition PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let S be the region in which $0 \leq y \leq 2$ whenever $1 \leq |x| \leq 3 $and $0 \leq y \leq 4$ whenever $|x|  \leq 1$. Suppose that $(X,Y)$ have a uniform distribution over S, and their joint PDF is given by $f_{x,y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{16}$, $(x,y) \in S$.

a). Find the marginal PDF $f_X(x)$ of $X$.

> Question 1: $f_X(x)= \begin{cases} \int_0^2 f(x,y) dy, & \text{whenever $1 \leq |x| \leq 3$} \\ \int_0^4 f(x,y)dy, & \text{whenever |x|<1} \end{cases}$ Is it right?

2).determine the conditional PDF $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

> Question 2: I got $\frac{1}{2}$ whenever $1 \leq |x| \leq 3$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ whenever $|x|<1$.

3). Find $E(Y\big|X=x)$

> Question 3: I got $E(Y|X=x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y f_Y|X(y|x)dy=\int_0^2 y\times \frac{1}{2} \times dy +\int_0^4 y\times \frac{1}{4} \times dy=3$ Is it correct?

4). Find $E(Y)$.

> By the law of total expectation, $E(Y)=E[E(Y\bigl|X)]=E[X]=0$ Is it right?

Comment: 2 is incorrect which consequently makes 3 incorrect, $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}$

Comment: @K.K.McDonald Can you help with fixing it? Thx!

Comment: $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}=\begin{cases}\frac{\frac{1}{16}}{\frac{1}{8}}=\frac{1}{2} \quad 1\le|x|\le3 \\ \frac{\frac{1}{16}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{4} \qquad\quad |x|<1&\end{cases}$. Try redoing the rest with this.